RandomForestClassifier OOB hyperprarameter
I am currently working with a RandomForest Classifier and I have conducted a RandomSearchCV to find optimum hyperparameters.
Now, I wanted to investigate in the OOB error and I am wondering If I plot the OOB error against a range of hyperparameters (I often see OOB against number of trees) if I can also kinda show that the OOB error decreases with the best hyperparameters.
Is that a valid way to do so?

For example, here you can see that the optimum is 1 samples lea
Thank you

Sure you can, whether it will be meaningful is another question, as these parameters are affecting each other.
